# Cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'system.func dynamic object ' MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm getting the mentioned error and "Invalid arguments" for WebGrid.column error in my view page.

//View

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.LoadProductDetails());
     @grid.GetHtml(
         tableStyle: "grid",
         fillEmptyRows: false,
         headerStyle: "gvHeading",
         alternatingRowStyle: "gvAlternateRow",
         rowStyle: "gvRow",
         footerStyle: "gvFooter",
         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
         firstText: "<< First",
         previousText: "< Prev",
         nextText: "Next >",
         lastText: "Last >>",
         columns: new[] {
         grid.Column("ProductId",header: "ID"),
         grid.Column("ProductName",header: "Product"),
         grid.Column("Price"),
         grid.Column("Qunatity"),     
         grid.Column("ReorderLevel", header: "R.O.L."),
         grid.Column("ContactusId", header: "Action", canSort:false, format: @<text> @Html.Raw("<img src='/img/edit.png' title='Edit' onclick='EditProduct("+ item.ProductId  ")'  />") @Html.Raw("<img src='/img/delete.png' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteProduct("+ item.ProductId +")'  />") </text>)       
     })    
}
```

The errors are thrown in the last column(ContactUsId) near the **format:**. Where i'm wrong?

Kindly help.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to inject client-side HTML into a server-side function call (which in turn generates client-side output). That is the opposite of how MVC works (code injects into the page HTML). You need to make those `@<>` into C# strings. Then it can be processed server-side and the resulting `GetHtml` method will inject the final result into the output.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Can you share a piece of code?

Comment: Sure thing. Example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: It looks like you are trying to inject client-side HTML into a server-side function call (which in turn generates client-side output). That is the opposite of how MVC works (code injects into the page HTML). You need to make those @<> into C# strings. Then it can be processed server-side and the resulting GetHtml method will inject the final result into the output.

### Example: Something like this

```
@{
    string template = "<text><img src='/img/edit.png' title='Edit' onclick='EditProduct("+ item.ProductId + ")' /><img src='/img/delete.png' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteProduct("+ item.ProductId +")' /></text>";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.LoadProductDetails());
     @grid.GetHtml(
         tableStyle: "grid",
         fillEmptyRows: false,
         headerStyle: "gvHeading",
         alternatingRowStyle: "gvAlternateRow",
         rowStyle: "gvRow",
         footerStyle: "gvFooter",
         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
         firstText: "<< First",
         previousText: "< Prev",
         nextText: "Next >",
         lastText: "Last >>",
         columns: new[] {
         grid.Column("ProductId",header: "ID"),
         grid.Column("ProductName",header: "Product"),
         grid.Column("Price"),
         grid.Column("Qunatity"),     
         grid.Column("ReorderLevel", header: "R.O.L."),
         grid.Column("ContactusId", header: "Action", canSort:false, format: template)    
}
```

Apologies for any typos, but this is just to indicate what you should be doing instead of trying to inject HTML into C# using Razor syntax (which would never work).

As a readability improvement I would use `string.Format` to replace markers in the template string.

e.g.

```
    string template = string.format("<text><img src='/img/edit.png' title='Edit' onclick='EditProduct({0})' /><img src='/img/delete.png' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteProduct({0})' /></text>", item.ProductId);
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? As I said in the anser, *apologies for any typos*. This was designed to point you in the right direction, not do all the coding for you :)

Comment: the same line in the last column.