# Named arguments specifications must appear after all fixed arguments in WebGrid MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, arguments, webgrid

I have to display if the Grid column value is "true" then "Yes" else "No". Tried in `WebGrid` but throwing me error in the `GridColumn` in View.

//Code:

```
  grid.Column("SelectedStatus", header: "Selected Status", Model.SelectedStatus==true ?  Html.Raw("Yes"):  Html.Raw("No"))
```

When i tried to use `format:` in the column it is throwing me `"Invalid arguments"` error.

Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. Firstly the error message which is fairly obvious - you understood that you needed to add a named argument at the end because fixed arguments cannot appear after named arguments.

Second, the format parameter is not a string but rather of expects a type `System.Func<Object, Object>` so you can replace it with:

```
grid.Column("SelectedStatus", "Selected Status", m => m.SelectedStatus == true ?  Html.Raw("Yes") : Html.Raw("No"))
```

You'll notice I removed the named `header` parameter too, because it's already the second argument in the list anyway so it is redundant here.

Finally, if `Model.SelectedStatus` is a `bool` (rather than a `bool?`) there is no need for the `== true`. You can simply write:

```
m => Html.Raw(m.SelectedStatus ? "Yes" : "No")
```

[WebGrid.Column Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.column%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Comment: Oops!!!. Comment removed. Its fine now. One question is how the lamda expression 'm' getting assigned to the Model?

Comment: Can you look into this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366843/cannot-convert-from-lambda-expression-to-system-func-dynamic-object-mvc3-ra